# Is there a way to log if Speak Screen is enabled in iOS

Tags: ios, accessibility, screen-readers

Is there a way to log Speak Screen accessibility settings in iOS?

I would like to check if this setting is turned on from within my app.

I have tried using `UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()` but this did not seem to log it when this flag was on.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIAccessibilityIsSpeakScreenEnabled()` to check whether **Speak Screen** is turn on.

**Note**: this method only relate to **Speak Screen** setting but not **Highlight Content**.